# sites_query = connection.execute("SELECT domain FROM django_site") psycopg2 has no attribute execute

Tags: django, postgresql, gunicorn, psycopg2, django-settings

When I try to start gunicorn, I am getting this error:

> File "/home/django-project/projectfolder/settings.py", line 270, in 
>       ALLOWED_HOSTS = get_allowed_hosts(DATABASES['default'])
>     File "/home/django-project/projectfolder/allowed_hosts.py", line 16, in get_allowed_hosts
>       sites_query = connection.execute("SELECT domain FROM django_site")
>   AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no attribute 'execute

```
from .settings import *

DEBUG = False


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'projectname_settings',
        'USER': '******',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "mydomain.com",
] + get_allowed_hosts(DATABASES['default'])
```

Allowed_hosts.py

```
def get_allowed_hosts(db_params):
    connection = None

    if db_params['ENGINE'] == 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2':
        import psycopg2
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user=db_params['USER'],
                                      password=db_params['PASSWORD'],
                                      host=db_params['HOST'],
                                      port=db_params['PORT'],
                                      database=db_params['NAME'])
    elif db_params['ENGINE'] == 'django.db.backends.sqlite3':
        import sqlite3
        connection = sqlite3.connect(db_params['NAME'])

    if connection is not None:
        sites_query = connection.execute("SELECT domain FROM django_site")
        sites_result = sites_query.fetchall()
        sites = ["." + site[0] for site in sites_result]
        print("Allowed hosts")
        print(sites)
        return sites
```

Comment: `DOMAIN` is a (non-reserved) keyword in SQL. Better not use it as an identifier. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: @wildplasser thanks, do u see anything that would also cause 502 errors? Is there special configuration of nginx/wsgi that are needed for this mechanism of allowed hosts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sould use `cursor` object to execute query:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
sites_query = cursor.execute("SELECT domain FROM django_site")
sites_result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Don't forget to close connection after get data:

```
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: I got an indentation error: 

```cursor = connection.cursor()
                               ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation``` 
even thought I've added the line as same level as site_query

Comment: @MoAlgh probably you are using tabs instead of spaces. Also check intents for all blocks of your code.

Comment: the erorr was solved and now I am getting 502 Bad Gateway error. Is this part of it?

Comment: I've ran all these commands

```sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
sudo systemctl restart nginx```

Comment: Hard to say without additional data. Try to ran it locally with DEBUG=True setting to see actual error message.

Comment: No errors locally, probably because I have a different settings file for development @neverwalkaloner